# Click button if it is present, else click a different button in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, ui-testing, puppeteer

I am trying to set up an `if/else` statement in puppeteer to click on a button if it is present, else click on another button. I am doing something like this:

```
if (document.querySelector('#buttonToClick') !== null) {
    await page.waitForSelector('#buttonToClick');
    await page.click('#buttonToClick');
  } 

else { 
// first click #otherButton and then click #buttonToClick
    await page.waitForSelector('#otherButton');
    await page.click('#otherButton');

    await page.waitForSelector('#buttonToClick');
    await page.click('#buttonToClick');
  }
```

For some reason I keep falling into the `else` block even when I go to my Chrome console and do a `document.querySelector('#buttonToClick') !==null` on the desired page and it is showing as `true`

**UPDATE**: The following code seems to be working for me, but I am not sure why

```
await page.waitFor(3000);

  if ((await page.$('#buttonToClick')) !== null) {
    await page.click('#buttonToClick');
  } else {
    await page.waitForSelector('#otherButton');
    await page.click('#otherButton');

    await page.waitForSelector('#buttonToClick');
    await page.click('#buttonToClick');
  }`
```

I thought maybe it might have something to do with the way the DOM loads, so I tried:

```
await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'})
// await page.waitFor(3000)

  if ((await page.$('#buttonToClick')) !== null) {
    await page.click('#buttonToClick');
  } else {
    await page.waitForSelector('#otherButton');
    await page.click('#otherButton');

    await page.waitForSelector('#buttonToClick');
    await page.click('#buttonToClick');
  }
```

But that didn't work...it only works with `await page.waitFor(30000)` before the `if` statement...any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe the result is ‘undefined’ so the !== null will always be true. Try it without the !==.. can you log document.querySelector(‘#buttonToClick’) and past the result here?

Comment: Can you post more of your `node.js` program? I was under the impression that `document.querySelector` would be part of your webpage and not part of the puppeteer program.

Comment: This is the result of running 
document.querySelector(#choose-file-button)
(the button I want to click) in the Chrome console:



`<button id="choose-file-button" class="mdl-typography--text-center mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored stem-grey-bg" data-upgraded=",MaterialButton">Upload New Files</button>`

Comment: await page.$ never returns null for me! I am trying to check if an element is on the page and it doesn't seem possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that `document.querySelector` normally exists inside a node.js program. Puppeteer does provide [`page.$`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector), which is a close analog. It  returns a Promise.

**Update**: With the new information in the question, it sounds like the part of the DOM tree that contains `#buttonToClick` is constructed after the DOMContentLoaded event. I've had good results using `page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })`, though 'networkidle2' or some other option might be better if you have lingering network connections. See the various options here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions

I suspect this should work:

```
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
if (await page.$('#buttonToClick') !== null) {
    await page.click('#buttonToClick');
  } else {
    await page.waitForSelector('#otherButton');
    await page.click('#otherButton');
  }
```

Comment: So this code you pasted got me on the right track, but it didn't work until I added:

`await page.waitFor(3000);

      if ((await page.$('#buttonToClick')) !== null) 
{
        await page.click('#buttonToClick');

      } 
        else {
        await page.waitForSelector('#otherButton');
        await page.click('#otherButton');
      }`
and then it worked...I don't like the idea of waiting for a fixed number of seconds though, feels brittle

Comment: I've updated my answer-- sounds like your page is adding the button after the `DOMContentLoaded` is fired.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help. I tried adding `await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });` and that didn't work, so then I tried adding `await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });` and that didn't work either :( 

The only thing that seems to work is the `await page.waitFor(3000)` for some odd reason...even `await page.waitFor(1000)` seems to work as well...I guess I will have to live with that lol

Comment: You might have some luck with setting `waitUntil` in your `page.goto` call, e.g. `page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })`. It sounds like it probably won't work though. For reference: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like what you really want is...

```
const btn = await Promise.race([
      page.waitForSelector('#buttonToClick'),
      page.waitForSelector('#otherButton')
]);

await btn.click()
```

i.e. wait for one or the other button. Whichever is found first, click that one. This will work even an SPA or ajax-based page where the buttons aren't there immediately upon load.

Comment: Thanks for this, would there be any way to tell which btn ended up getting clicked? Here is how things happen on the site im testing:

Is #buttonToClick available? If yes, click it and move on.

Else, click #otherButton and then click #buttonToClick.



I think your above scenario would work for my "If" case, but in the "Else" case I would need to first click the #otherButton and then click the #buttonToClick, in which case I would know which button actually got clicked after `await btn.click()` if that makes sense?

Comment: I've been using Puppeteer for all of 10 minutes, so I don't know, but I'm sure there's ample juicy details in the `btn` object that will tell you which one it found. Once you know what it is, you can click or not click or do whatever you need to do.